# numpy.ravel giving 2D array - can anyone explain?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I've come across some code where the use of numpy.ravel() is resulting in a 2D array - I've had a look at the documentation, which says that ravel() returns a 1D array (see https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html).

Here's a code snippet that shows this:

```
def jumbo():
    import numpy as np
    my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    matrix = np.zeros((3,3))
    matrix.ravel()[:] = my_list
    return matrix

new_matrix = jumbo()
print(f"new matrix is:\n{new_matrix}")
```

I suppose part of what I'm asking is what is the function of the range specifier [:] here?

Comment: Sorry about the code snippet - I missed that the formatting disappeared in the preview...

Comment: please note the this "trick" will only work for C-contiguous arrays

Answer (score 1):

What you did is assigned values at "raveled" matrix, wihtout actually saving ravel operation.

```
matrix = np.empty((3,3))  # created empty matrix
matrix.ravel()  # created 1d view of matrix
matrix.ravel()[:]  # indexing every element of matrix to make assignment possible (matrix is still in (3,3) shape)
matrix.ravel()[:] = my_list  #  assigned values.
```

if you want return to be 1D then return raveled array like this

```
def jumbo():
    import numpy as np
    my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    matrix = np.empty((3,3))
    matrix.ravel()[:] = my_list
    return matrix.ravel()

new_matrix = jumbo()
print(f"new matrix is:\n{new_matrix}")
```

Comment: Many thanks, this adds to my understanding. The original code takes a long list which needs to be assigned to a 2D square matrix, so I won't be taking advantage of your code to return a 1D array (at least for this project!)

Answer (score 0):

`ravel` returns a **view** of the numpy array, thus when you do:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
matrix = np.zeros((3,3))
matrix.ravel()[:] = my_list
```

You are using the view as a way to index the `matrix` as 1D, **temporarily**.

This enables here to set the values from a 1D list, but the underlying array remains 2D.

The `matrix.ravel()[:]` is used to enable setting the data. You could also use 2 steps:

```
view = matrix.ravel()
view[:] = my_list
```

output:

```
array([[1., 2., 3.],
       [4., 5., 6.],
       [7., 8., 9.]])
```

##### important note on the views

As @Stef nicely pointed out in the comments, ***this "trick" will only work for C-contiguous arrays***, meaning you couldn't use `ravel('F')`:

demonstration:

```
view1 = matrix.ravel()
view2 = matrix.ravel('F') # actually not a view!

id(matrix)
# 140406991308816
id(view1.base)
# 140406991308816
id(view2.base)
# 9497104          # different id, we have a copy!
```

Comment: Many thanks, beautifully clear explanation which makes very good sense to me.